# Accessing nginx through local ip

Tags: networking, virtualization, nginx

I have installed Ubuntu on virtual machine and I have installed nginx on it. When i run it as localhost and 10.0.2.15 it works fine but when i try to access it outside of virtual machine using same network it fails to connect

Comment: Cant tell from what you posted. What VM (KVM Virtualbox)? What networking (NAT, bridged) ? Could be firewall as well.

Answer (score 0):

hate to post it myself 10.0.2.15 was not my ip for the local network i just changed the oracle virtual machine settings and then from the network I used the ipv4 ip under wired. Works fine now